# Скачивание файла из интернета

Tags: java, android, url

Здравствуйте.Имеется код который скачивает файл из  интернета

```
private static void downloadUsingStream(String urlStr, String file) throws IOException{
    URL url = new URL(urlStr);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fis = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int count=0;
    while((count = bis.read(buffer,0,1024)) != -1)
    {
        fis.write(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    fis.close();
    bis.close();
}
```

Пару недель назад файл скачивался все как надо.А сегодня заметил что не качается.Стал разбираться, ошибок нет, но выяснил что почему то скачивается 180Кб из 9Мб.Что я делаю не так и как решить проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, проблем может быть много. Самые простые, которые я вижу, исходя из того, что все работало:

1. Могла закончится память в телефоне.
2. Может быть что-то не так с файлом в интернете.

Comment: Разобрался.Просто файл который я хочу скачать не по этому адресу а редиректом

Comment: @Ivan, то есть мой второй вариант. Примите ответ, если именно он помог Вам решить проблему.